# Undeclared issue, not sure how to fix

Tags: c++, vector, void

This program is meant to store a list of usernames, add usernames, and delete them as well. My code works as intended except for the first step. Whenever i enter a name to be stored nothing shows up on the list, and because of this nothing can be deleted. Im not sure where i messed up because i went over it and everything looks fine. I also do not get any error messages so i dont have any direction as to what i should be looking for. Any help would be great, thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using std::cout, std::cin, std::string, std::vector;

void printUserList(vector<string> listUser) {
    cout << "Current User List\n";

    for(int x = 0; x < listUser.size(); ++x) {
        cout << x << "" << listUser[x] << "\n";
    }
}

int main() {
    vector<string> addUser;
    vector<string> userBase;
    string userName;
    char choice;
    bool keepLooping = true;

    while(keepLooping) {
        cout << "User Options:\n"
             << "1. Add a username\n"
             << "2. List all username\n"
             << "3. Delete a username\n"
             << "X. Exit\n";
        cout << "Enter Option: ";
        cin >> choice;
        cin.ignore();

        switch(choice) {
        case '1': {
            cout << "Enter username: ";
            getline(cin, userName);
            cout << "\n";

            if(userName.size() > 0) {
                addUser.push_back(userName);
                cout << "User has been added\n\n";
            }

        } break;

        case '2': {
            printUserList(userBase);
        } break;

        case '3': {
            int index;
            printUserList(userBase);

            cout << "Enter the index of the user: ";
            cin >> index;
            cin.ignore();

            if(index < userBase.size()) {
                userBase.erase(userBase.begin() + index);

                cout << "User deleted";
            }

        } break;

        case 'X': {
            userBase.clear();
            keepLooping = false;
        } break;

        default: {
            cout << "Option not found, please try again.";
        }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 separate `vector` objects - `addUser` and `userBase`.  You are adding all of your usernames to `addUser` only, but you are printing and deleting usernames from `userBase` instead.  That is why you don't see anything.

Get rid of `addUser` altogether, you don't need it.  Add your usernames to `userBase` instead.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you add the user to a `vector` (named `addUser`) that you don't use for anything but adding users.

```
        case '1': {
            cout << "Enter username: ";
            getline(cin, userName);
            cout << "\n";

            if(userName.size() > 0) {
                addUser.push_back(userName);       //  <- here
                cout << "User has been added\n\n";
            }

        } break;
```

In all the other places you're using a different `vector`, `userBase`, so change the above line to

```
                userBase.push_back(userName);
```